# Can elements in JasperReports be configured to float down instead of up?

Tags: jasper-reports, floating

In JasperReports in the footer, I have 3 elements on the same vertical position (they have also the same height) at the very bottom of the page footer section. These 3 elements represents Address block, Contact block (e-mail, ww, etc) and a VAT block (from left to right).

Now I have some occations, where below these 3 elements an advertising footer has to be inserted.

As the 3 elements are already at the very bottom of the page, the advertising header cannot be positioned more down.

The goal is to dynamically "push" these 3 elements up the dynamic height of the advertising header when the advertising footer contains some text.

This is similar to the standard "float" behavior of an element which pushes it down when the above element grows in height - but this time it has to work in the opposite direction (being pushed up but trying to stay as much to the bottom as possible.

---

I have already tried to create an advertising footer with 0 (also with 1) px height, set position type to "fix relative to bottom" and to declare this as stretch with overflow.

--> Doesn't stretch the advertising footer upwards from the fix bottom but seems to stretch it more down (out of printable range).

---

I am a bit of lost here as it seems that the whole jasperReport solution is mainly done from top to down and I could not find any hint in my researchs to acomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the whole footer into a subreport and actually creating two different subreports:

- one which only shows the 3 existing blocks
- one which shows the advertising footer below the 3 (moved up) blocks

And then on the Master Report I have both subreports within the footer at the same position and use the print when expression to either include the 1st or the 2nd subreport.

Hope this helps someone.